# Adding textfield input to label

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I feel like this is a rookie question but I'm stumped. The app will become much more complex than this (subtraction, division, multiplication, math) but in order to work from a foundation... Well, I don't even have a foundation.

```
-(IBAction)change:(id)sender {
NSString *xText = x.text;
int xValue = [xText intValue];

NSString *yText = y.text;
int yValue = [yText intValue];

int zValue = xValue + yValue;
NSString *zText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", zValue];
zText = z.text;
```

Basically what I'm trying to do right now is have two separate text fields collect user-typed numbers. When the "Calculate" button is pressed, the label will change to show the answer. (i.e. x = 4, y = 3, press calculate, z label changes to 7)

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The label doesn't change when the calculate button is pressed.

Comment: The last line should be `z.text = zText;` assuming `z` is the `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you would like to add the zText to a label?

Simply go:

```
[label setText:zText];
```

Where label is the IBOutlet to your label

Comment: Wow do I feel silly. That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @collinhaines Fantastic!  If you could accept my answer, it would be much appreciated :)